# Mediapipe deadlock resolver

Tags: graph, mediapipe

I have primary input (reader) and secondary (generator), both of them are source nodes. When I don't have the primary input (from reader), I want to output data from generator. My primary input goes into some calculation part, where it can require multiple packets before the first output. When I don't have generator and the primary reader is throttled (because of reach of the max packets in the queue), mediapipe resolve this deadlock automatically. When I have second input source (generator), mediapipe does not try to unthrottle my primary source node, because it tries to do it only in case when all source nodes are throttled. How to deal with this problem? Should I make custom deadlock resolver, or convert generator to simple node instead of source node. Maybe someone know the best practice for this case?